# ruby on rails custom action for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I'm trying to use form_for for a custom action. My code right now does not cause any errors, it just doesn't do anything. I've been stuck on this for a while, any help would be great :)

routes.rb

```
 resources :posts do
     member do
     patch :confirm
   end
 end
```

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed.any? %>
  <% @feed.each do |feed| %>

  <span class="props_form">
  <form class="form-inline">

    <%= form_for @post, url: confirm_post_path(feed), method: :patch do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                  # form fields
                <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Confirm", class: "btn-primary btn-xs form-control" %>
                </div>
    <% end %>

  </form>
  </span>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def confirm
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @post.toggle!(:confirm)
    @post.save
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  if logged_in?
    @feed = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

model user.rb

```
def feed
  Post.where("user_id = ?", id)
end
```

Comment: What is a feed? `params[:id]` in the controller gives you id of the feed that you pass to the `confirm_post_path` helper in the form.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've edited my question to include the feed method in my user model and the @feed in my pages controller. I'm able to confirm that the partial is extracting information from each feed, however my form_for is not triggering the code in my confirm action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In _feed.html.erb you are using nested form (form tag in form tag), so inner form which is written in erb isn't generated.
And I don't get it why you are using form_for with @post.
Here is mine solution.

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed.any? %>
    <% @feed.each do |feed| %>
        <span class="props_form">
            <%= form_tag confirm_post_path(feed), class: 'form-inline', method: :patch do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                # form fields
                <div class="form-group">
                <%= submit_tag "Confirm", class: "btn-primary btn-xs form-control" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I'm not using a nested form, the # form fields is just attributes that I want to update.

Comment: I meant that you have <%=form_for.. %> in <form class="form-inline"> HTML tag. I didn't mean nested attributes or something like that.

Comment: I removed the <form class...> HTML tag and I got it working. I was just using the tag to get the format I wanted. Functionality works, now I'm working on getting the format to look the way I want it to.

Comment: Why don't you use `<%= form_tag confirm_post_path(feed), class: 'form-inline', method: :patch do |f| %> (form_tag with class attribute)?
`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Here is the solution I got to work: <%= form_for @post, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}, url: confirm_post_path(feed), method: :patch, :remote=>true do |f| %>